# Can you put queries into functions?

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I am working with a database and trying to create a theatre booking website where the customers can input their details to perform an order, I want to separate queries for the customer details and performance details etc. Could I use functions to separate it out? Or am I going the wrong way about it? this is what I have so far.

```
<?php
$connectdb = mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password", "database")
        or die("Error ".mysqli_connect_error($connectdb));

function customerDetails(){
    mysqli_query($connectdb, "QUERY GOES HERE");
}


mysqli_close($connectdb);
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: You could do that, sure. You could also seperate them using conditional statements and fire off a function with what's been chosen based on which button was clicked. Many ways to do this.

Comment: You can even go one step further and create a mysql or a db class with the connection information as a constructor. You can then write generic functions that take various arguments to perform the operations that you would like to perform. Its like using an ORM/DBAL etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the variable `$connectdb` is defined in the global scope (outside any function), and to use it inside a function you need to import it using the [global](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) keyword:

```
function customerDetails(){
    global $connectdb;
    mysqli_query($connectdb, "QUERY GOES HERE");
}
```

Creating functions to retrieve data is good mostly because it abstracts the code and makes it re-usable. That is: you can call `customerDetails()` in more than one page, and if one day you want to switch from MySQL to MongoDB (for example), you just need to update that function. It's not really for performance reasons at runtime (actually, without a function it should be *slightly* faster), but it makes development much more easy and efficient (and cost-effective).

Comment: `function customerDetails($connectdb)` is another method, without having to declare as a global. Many fear that using global is evil.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Personally, I would have created a class with an abstraction layer to do all database communication. However, given the type of question that the original poster asked, I'd rather go step-by-step with the easy way first

Comment: si "Someone", I mean "Qualcuno" ;-) è una buona idea